# Base64 file encoding that is large

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

is there any way to encode file that has for example 2GB without "chopping" it for chunks? Because files larger than 2GB throw error that file is too large for fs. And making it smaller chunks dont work either, cause of encoding/decoding problem. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Base64 isn't a good solution for large file transfer.

It's simple, and easy to work with, but will increase your file size.  See [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) about this.  I would recommend looking into best practices for data transfer in JS. MDN has an other [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) on this that breaks down the DataTransfer API.

> ###### Encoded size increase
>
> Each Base64 digit represents exactly 6 bits of data. So, three 8-bits bytes of the input string/binary file (3×8 bits
> = 24 bits) can be represented by four 6-bit Base64 digits (4×6 = 24 bits).
>
> This means that the Base64 version of a string or file will be at
> least 133% the size of its source (a ~33% increase). The increase may
> be larger if the encoded data is small. For example, the string "a"
> with length === 1 gets encoded to "YQ==" with length === 4 — a 300%
> increase.

##### Additionally

Could share what you're trying to do, and add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  There are so many different ways to tackle this problem, it's hard to narrow it down without knowing any of the requirements.

Comment: If its not a good solution, then how can I convert png to text without base64? Is there anything?

Comment: What is the highest level goal?  Rather than convert a PNG to text, are you trying to move a PNG to a database? To an other server? To a cloud storage provider?

Comment: I want to make something like any file like PNG or ZIP to text (base64 then my encoding that makes base64 shorter) then this text to file that was selected before encoding to base 1:1